# Can the scope of this for loop be any smaller?

Tags: java, boolean

Besides moving this behavior to a method somewhere or shifting around whitespace, can the variable scope of this code be slimmed down in any way?

```
boolean a = true;
boolean b = false;
boolean c = false;
boolean d = false;
boolean e = false;

{
boolean[] multiBool = { a, b, c, d, e };

int isTrue = 0;
for (boolean bool : multiBool)
   if (bool && ++isTrue > 1) {
      System.out.println("More than 1!");

      break;
   }
}
```

I was surprised to find out that I can't inline the initializer list:

```
for (boolean bool : { a, b, c, d, e }) {}
```

The surrounding `{` and `}` are to limit the scope of `multiBool` and `isTrue` as they are only relevant to this particular case.

Comment: What about `for (boolean bool : new boolean[] { a,b,c,d,e })` ?

Comment: you can do `for (boolean bool : new boolean[]{ true, false, false, false, false }) {}`, i have no clue why you´d need the 5 variables though

Comment: Ahh! This is what I was trying to do. Curious that I need a `new` here.

Comment: @khelwood was the first to comment and I will accept his answer first if he chooses to submit one.

Comment: @Zhro No need, Eran's answer covers it perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (boolean bool : { a, b, c, d, e }) {}
```

is not valid, but this is :

```
for (boolean bool : new boolean[] { a, b, c, d, e }) {}
```

You can further slim down your code by eliminating the boolean variables :

```
int isTrue = 0;
for (boolean bool : new boolean[]{true,false,false,false,false}) {
   if (bool && ++isTrue > 1) {
      System.out.println("More than 1!");
      break;
   }
}
```

Of course, if the values of the boolean variables are known in advance, you don't need the for loop at all, since you already know there is only one `true` value.

Comment: Not sure if you're serious regarding the list of literal boolean values. Too much code golf?

Comment: 0-bytes answer confirmed!